# fclose: no space left on device when installing kali linux on laptop

Tags: kali-linux, system-installation

I'm trying to install Kali Linux on my laptop, and after partitioning it says fclose: no space left on device, though my HDD has 1TB. These are my laptop specs: I3-7100, 4GB RAM, 1TB HDD. I don't know what to do, I'm kinda new to linux so I'm asking for your help. I'm sure I selected the HDD. Thank you!

Comment: If you are new to linux, then find another user friendly distro. Get an RPi and install it and learn the basics. kali is not designed for novices.